# Using ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION to sequentially renumber a field in a new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code I've compiled so far ... (Specifically focus on the BUILD_NUM part)

```
SELECT        CNS_PID, CNS_BID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CNS_PID ORDER BY CNS_PID) AS BUILD_NUM, CNS_SECT_NUM
FROM          REAL_PROP.CONSTRCOM
```

Works when there are distinct values in CNS_BID, but it doesn't work if CNS_BID occasionally repeats, which it can because a BID (buidling) can have multiple sections (CNS_SECT_NUM)

Here's my (not what I need) results... (BUILD_NUM)

| CNS_PID | CNS_BID | BUILD_NUM | CNS_SECT_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 1 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 2 | 2 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 3 | 3 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 4 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 5 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 6 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 7 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 8 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 9 | 2 |

Here's what I need... (BUILD_NUM)

| CNS_PID | CNS_BID | BUILD_NUM | CNS_SECT_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 1 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 2 |
| 2656 | 2656 | 1 | 3 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 2 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170166 | 2 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 3 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170167 | 3 | 2 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 4 | 1 |
| 2656 | 170168 | 4 | 2 |

So basically, For each CNS_PID I need each unique CNS_BID to be identified/renumbered 1,2,3,4, etc, which then RESETS for each CNS_PID.

I want to be able to know at quick glance that this CNS_PID has 4 distinct CNS_BID's, (Since each CNS_BID has distinct CNS_SECT_NUMS) If there's no way to do this, that's fine, I will just be stuck with CNS_BID as the identifier, it's just not as orderly and intuitive.

Comment: Did you try something? For example: `DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CNS_PID ORDER BY CNS_BID)`

Comment: Stop and think about why partitioning and ordering on the same value makes no sense.

Comment: @shawnt00 - ah man, I see what you mean.  I think that was a typo on my part, and I'm not expert enough to catch it.  Thanks.

Comment: @siggemannen - yep, that works, thanks!  I'm very grateful.  Also very frustrated that I didn't figure this out on my own.  I can't work with this every day (because I have other job duties), but since I'm the ONLY one in the office with even basic knowledge of SQL, this stuff always gets put on me to solve.

Comment: @TomkatDF2 glad it worked out! And yeah, it's alright, sometimes one concentrates on ROW_NUMBER and forgets that there are other functions which can be useful!

Comment: FYI, for future reference, you always need to show the sample (starting/raw) data in addition to the desired results.

Comment: @DaleK - sorry about that.  The raw data was basically the first table without my added "BUILD_NUM" field.  I didn't want to clutter up the question/post too much.

Comment: @DaleK, I actually found an instance in my data results where Dense Rank failed to work as intended.  Should I post a new question?

Comment: Yes you can't make changes to a question you have already accepted an answer to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT     CNS_PID, CNS_BID, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cns_pid ORDER BY cns_bid) AS BUILD_NUM, CNS_SECT_NUM
FROM       REAL_PROP.CONSTRCOM 
ORDER BY   CNS_PID, CNS_BID
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/CEtc_iUT